# Is is simple to create a Biztalk adapter for an arbitrary XML source service?

Tags: xml, biztalk

I'm trying to find out if it's simple / easy to create a Biztalk adapter for an arbitrary XML source, (ie. not a WSDL/SOAP/RPC etc.)

Are there any factors that will make this simpler, for example, DTD/XSD for the XML service.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to route the consumed data to a MSSQL database, and I'd like to know how much Biztalk is likely to simplify this process, vs, consuming the XML via a custom C#/.Net solution.

Sorry if the question is vague, but I'm inexperienced with BizTalk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main benefit you will get from BizTalk is the platform for reliability of message processing and tracking. Another point is message routing: As soon as you want to deliver your data to more than one endpoint you will begin to gain over a custom C#/.Net solution.
The most common use case would be a Publish-Subscribe scenario where BizTalk separates "upstream" and "downstream" systems.

Furthermore BizTalk is a good place to handle specific business rules around your data streams (hence the "Biz").

If however your goal is a mere transforming data pump into a database BizTalk would be an expensive overhead.

As specific to your central question "Is it simple to create a BizTalk adapter?" the answer is definitly "yes". Developing, deploying and running BizTalk applications is pretty straightforward ... today. Versions prior to BizTalk 2009 did show their lack of a seamless integration into the MS stack. Compared to products like Exchange or SQL Server 2008, BizTalk 2009 is still  a step behind - for example PowerShell is not integrated like in these other products.

A well defined DTD/XSD for the messages you are going to exchange with your source and target systems is big plus because it enables you to track and monitor message variables.

Comment: Our plan is to integrate other systems down the line, my initial thinking was to consume the xml feed and populate a central database, using either a C#/.Net custom solution or use BizTalk, our primary motivating factor is time to deliver a solution. If it would be straightforward to connect BizTalk to a WCF service layer (which I assume it would be) later down the line, that would be sufficient to meet our wider goals for integration with BizTalk.

Comment: BizTalk becomes good on ROI the more Integration points you have.  If its only a few integration points it might not be the best tool to use.

Comment: @slomojo In that case BizTalk will clearly speed up your development process and as I already mentioned you will build onto a platform that is made for decoupling your source and target systems.

Comment: @Filburt - my biggest concern is about this initial incoming feed/service. It requires custom/arbitrary XML message ACK's and request packages, is this something that BizTalk will handle easily?

Comment: @slomojo From what I'm dealing with I can say that BizTalk can handle even strange and non-standard messaging. For example our CRM system cannot deal with Xml namespaces but we were able to make BizTalk to handle this. Still in one case we had to build a custom http module to receive messages because the other system could not talk to the builtin http receiver. Maybe you could post some sample messages you'll have to deal with.

Comment: Sure, I'll post some example messaging exchanges tomorrow, (it's late here now and I'm out of the office.) In a nutshell though, we have sequential data XML messages for a specific authenticated account (from the legacy service) which we send an XML message to request, and then send an XML acknowledgement message when we receive it, or resend the request if message reception fails for some reason, after a given timeout.